# Sorting List of Strings Insensitively

Tags: string, sorting, haskell, quicksort

Im trying to sort a list of strings insensitively in Haskell, but im getting cryptic error messages. Here's my code:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List
import Data.Char (toUpper)


sortme :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sortme n = quickSort insensitively n

insensitively :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Ordering
insensitively string1 string2 = compare (map toUpper string1) (map toUpper string2)


quickSort :: (Ord a) => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
quickSort _ [] = []
quickSort c (x : xs) = (quickSort c less) ++ (x : equal) ++ (quickSort c more)
    where
        less  = filter (\y -> y `c` x == LT) xs
        equal = filter (\y -> y `c` x == EQ) xs
        more  = filter (\y -> y `c` x == GT) xs
```

quickSort takes an ordering function and a list of strings, and sorts the strings by the ordering function. insensitively is the ordering function. Here's my error message:

```
/tmp/haskell114913-7-1rjcqe8/Sort.hs:11:54:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [Char])
    from the context (Ord a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 insensitively :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
      at /tmp/haskell114913-7-1rjcqe8/Sort.hs:10:18-49
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for insensitively :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
          at /tmp/haskell114913-7-1rjcqe8/Sort.hs:10:18
    In the second argument of `map', namely `string1'
    In the first argument of `compare', namely `(map toUpper string1)'
    In the expression:
      compare (map toUpper string1) (map toUpper string2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function definitions are fine, your type signatures are the problem.  If you were to delete the type signatures it would compile.  The problem is that you've said that `insensitively` and `sortme` sort any `Ord a`, but you've used `map toUpper`, which means that it can only sort strings.  Just make the signatures more specific:

```
sortme :: [String] -> [String]
insensitively :: String -> String -> Ordering
```

---

So you viewed this error message as cryptic, so let's break it down.  The error message is really:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ [Char])
from the context (Ord a)
  bound by the type signature for
             insensitively :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
  Sort.hs:10:18-49
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for insensitively :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
      at Sort.hs:10:18
In the second argument of `map', namely `string1'
In the first argument of `compare', namely `(map toUpper string1)'
In the expression:
  compare (map toUpper string1) (map toUpper string2)
```

With some of the noise of file names removed.  The first part to look at is

> Could not deduce `(a ~ [Char])` from the context `(Ord a)`

The `~` symbol means equality for types.  What the compiler is saying is you've said that the signature has an `Ord a => a` in it, but the definition says that it must be `[Char]`, not just any `Ord a` in

> the type signature for `insensitively :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering`

This means that you've said `insensitively` compares any two `Ord a` values, but the function definition only works when `a` is `[Char]`.  The Rest of the error message just tells you where in your code the error is located:

> In the second argument of `map`, namely `string1`
>
> In the first argument of `compare`, namely `(map toUpper string1)`
>
> In the expression: `compare (map toUpper string1) (map toUpper string2)`